# Making query in separate thread leaves list view empty

Tags: android

I'm initializing an adapter with a cursor, and setting the adapter to a listview.

```
DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
Cursor c = dbh.getMoviesTableCursor();
myAdapter =  new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity(), c, 0);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

When I make the query in `dbh.getMoviesTableCursor()` method, I run said query in seperate thread

```
private Cursor getMoviesTableCursor(){

    ...

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            moviesTableCursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);

        }
    }.start();

    ...

    return moviesTableCursor;
}
```

Now my listview does not show anything, versus when I did not run the query in a new thread like so

```
private Cursor getMoviesTableCursor(){

    ...
    moviesTableCursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, 
    ...

    return moviesTableCursor;
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it works as expected. Your `query` run in another thread, your `getMoviesTableCursor` run in UI thread --> then `getMoviesTableCursor` will return an empty cursor. To avoid it, you should rewrite your code like:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        moviesTableCursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // use handler to avoid update UI from none-UI thread.
            //do your update list view adapter here.
        }
    });

    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I update the adapter? `setnotifyDataSetChanged()` or `swapCursor()` because neither of them appear to be working

Comment: swap cursor is the better solution for you in this case :)